# How to check if string2 has characters not in string1?

Tags: c

```
char String1 = "1234567890+-";
char String2 = "1+a";
```

String2 is an input and I want to check if it contains any character that is not in String1.

I have tried using `strpbrk(String2,String1)` but this returns true as long as any character in `String1` exists in `String2`.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: How about `strcspn`?

Comment: `for(char *c=str2; *c; c++) if (strchr(str1,*c)==0) {printf("error: %c",*c); break;} if (!*c) printf("ok");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strspn` will return the index of the first character in String2 that is not in String1. If all the characters match, the index will be to the terminating zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void) {
    char *String1 = "1234567890+-";
    char *String2 = "1+a";
    int index = strspn ( String2, String1);
    if ( String2[index]) {
        printf ( "character \'%c\' not found in %s\n", String2[index], String1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simplified version of `union-find`.

First, you loop over `string1` and mark all the characters with `1`. I write simplified code, you can complete it.

```
char mark[255];
for(s=string1; s; s++) mark[*s]=1;
```

Next, you loop over `string2` and check if the current char is marked.

```
for(s=string2; s; s++) if (!mark[*s]) printf("%c", *s);
```

This will print all chars from `string2` that are not in `string1`.

Comment: You forgot to initialize `mark` (not UB, but potentially wrong result), and to cast `*s` to `unsigned char` for indexing (potential UB).